# Browser Full screen feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

Hi I have the below page where you simply click the button Full screen and the page browser takes up the full screen, the navigation controls are also hidden to - which is what I like. However if you page refresh (or in my case my page refreshes every 5 minutes) the navigation controls return and it is no longer the view as previous. How can I solve this so that when it refreshed the navigation etc doesn't return and it remains full screen?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script src="screenfull.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#supported').text('Supported/allowed: ' + !!screenfull.enabled);

        if (!screenfull.enabled) {
            return false;
        }

        $('#request').click(function () {
            screenfull.request($('#container')[0]);
            // does not require jQuery, can be used like this too:
            // screenfull.request(document.getElementById('container'));
        });

        $('#exit').click(function () {
            screenfull.exit();
        });

        function fullscreenchange() {
            var elem = screenfull.element;

            $('#status').text('Is fullscreen: ' + screenfull.isFullscreen);

            if (elem) {
                $('#element').text('Element: ' + elem.localName + (elem.id ? '#' + elem.id : ''));
            }

            if (!screenfull.isFullscreen) {
                $('#external-iframe').remove();
                document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener(screenfull.raw.fullscreenchange, fullscreenchange);

        // set the initial values
        fullscreenchange();
    });
    </script>
    <button id="request"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i> Request</button>
    <button id="exit">Exit</button>
</body>
```

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var isCommonjs = typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports;
var keyboardAllowed = typeof Element !== 'undefined' && 'ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT' in Element;

var fn = (function () {
    var val;
    var valLength;

    var fnMap = [
        [
            'requestFullscreen',
            'exitFullscreen',
            'fullscreenElement',
            'fullscreenEnabled',
            'fullscreenchange',
            'fullscreenerror'
        ],
        // new WebKit
        [
            'webkitRequestFullscreen',
            'webkitExitFullscreen',
            'webkitFullscreenElement',
            'webkitFullscreenEnabled',
            'webkitfullscreenchange',
            'webkitfullscreenerror'

        ],
        // old WebKit (Safari 5.1)
        [
            'webkitRequestFullScreen',
            'webkitCancelFullScreen',
            'webkitCurrentFullScreenElement',
            'webkitCancelFullScreen',
            'webkitfullscreenchange',
            'webkitfullscreenerror'

        ],
        [
            'mozRequestFullScreen',
            'mozCancelFullScreen',
            'mozFullScreenElement',
            'mozFullScreenEnabled',
            'mozfullscreenchange',
            'mozfullscreenerror'
        ],
        [
            'msRequestFullscreen',
            'msExitFullscreen',
            'msFullscreenElement',
            'msFullscreenEnabled',
            'MSFullscreenChange',
            'MSFullscreenError'
        ]
    ];

    var i = 0;
    var l = fnMap.length;
    var ret = {};

    for (; i < l; i++) {
        val = fnMap[i];
        if (val && val[1] in document) {
            for (i = 0, valLength = val.length; i < valLength; i++) {
                ret[fnMap[0][i]] = val[i];
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }

    return false;
})();

var screenfull = {
    request: function (elem) {
        var request = fn.requestFullscreen;

        elem = elem || document.documentElement;

        // Work around Safari 5.1 bug: reports support for
        // keyboard in fullscreen even though it doesn't.
        // Browser sniffing, since the alternative with
        // setTimeout is even worse.
        if (/5\.1[\.\d]* Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            elem[request]();
        } else {
            elem[request](keyboardAllowed && Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
    },
    exit: function () {
        document[fn.exitFullscreen]();
    },
    toggle: function (elem) {
        if (this.isFullscreen) {
            this.exit();
        } else {
            this.request(elem);
        }
    },
    raw: fn
};

if (!fn) {
    if (isCommonjs) {
        module.exports = false;
    } else {
        window.screenfull = false;
    }

    return;
}

Object.defineProperties(screenfull, {
    isFullscreen: {
        get: function () {
            return Boolean(document[fn.fullscreenElement]);
        }
    },
    element: {
        enumerable: true,
        get: function () {
            return document[fn.fullscreenElement];
        }
    },
    enabled: {
        enumerable: true,
        get: function () {
            // Coerce to boolean in case of old WebKit
            return Boolean(document[fn.fullscreenEnabled]);
        }
    }
});

if (isCommonjs) {
    module.exports = screenfull;
} else {
    window.screenfull = screenfull;
}
})();
```

#### Online Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/zx0rXwXpJbWdMvh3HQ25?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

1. Make onepage website (ajax) (no refresh) Use history pushstate to save all your links so you can use history navigation and change your URL. (most of time I use this approach.)
2. Or you can use localstorage to save state.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically You can store an indication of what was the previews state (`full-screen / normal`) in the browser storage.
Then on page load, read the stored value and activate full-screen if necessary.

**However,** modern browsers require this to be an interactive user action (not automatically via script on load)

If you try [to automate this](https://plnkr.co/edit/zx0rXwXpJbWdMvh3HQ25?p=preview), you'll get these type of warnings in the browser's console:

[image]

#### Alternatives

- Avoid full refreshes
- Workaround using custom browser extension to restore the fullscreen state

Comment: will trigger click on link also not work? btw, your example is 404

Comment: will not work since this should be driven by a real "click" and not by a simulated one.
updated example link (make sure you click on the "open in a new window"  button on plunker's preview)

Comment: Thanks for the info!!